# Sentimental Analysis using Naive Bayes

Tags: facebook, twitter, machine-learning, mahout, sentiment-analysis

I am working on problem solution where I am collecting social feeds from twitter and Facebook for a **product X** . I am labeling these posts,comments or tweets using five labels

```
--Positive
--Negative
--Campaign 
--Reply
--Queries
```

I have a training set of around 5000 which includes tweets,Facebook posts and Comments .
But these training set are unbalanced and have more of Negatives and Campaign data . Below is the list of sentiments and their count:

```
--Positive--> 492
--Negative--> 2193
--Campaign--> 1422
--Reply--> 430
--Queries--> 922
```

I am using Naive Bayes for predicting these sentiments . As you can see the above training set is high unbalanced is there any way that I can improve my model with these training set .
Any suggestion for improving my prediction model would be helpful .

I am using Mahout for these building this prediction model .

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried the simple way of ignoring class balance? It doesn't really matter for naive Bayes anyway (priors are swamped by likelihood terms, see David Hand's paper Idiot Bayes: Not So Stupid After All? http://www.jstor.org/stable/1403452). Do you know that just using your data as is doesn't work?

Comment: @BenAllison I know that ! I have converted them into vectors .

Comment: sorry---what does converting them to vectors have to do with what I said?

Comment: I am asking is this right algorithm for this problem statement ?

Comment: What I meant was, just take all your feature vectors with the current class balance and apply Naive Bayes, without rebalancing. It should work fine, in Naive Bayes at least, for the reasons outlined in the paper I linked. Only when it doesn't work well enough should you try to change---the smallest category has 430 examples, which should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks for that @BenAllison . Currently I am getting 60 percent accuracy . Is there any way i can improve ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45720/discussion-between-ben-allison-and-deepesh-shetty)

Comment: You may also want to try logistic regression and svm. They perform better than NB for this kind of classification problem. For unbalanced data, regularization should help

Comment: If I want to use logistic Regression Algorithm in Mahout . What steps in need to follow . any idea ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mahout, but it should use the same feature file format as NB.